# How do I use an asynchronous query to read in a list of to-dos?

Tags: vue.js, async-await

I'm making a simple to-do list application but I need to use an asynch query to fill the tasks on the webpage with what is in the json (I am given a link where the list of todos are). How do I do this? I've been searching everywhere and am stuck. Right now, it is only showing tasks I add, or a task I have manually inputted under data.

This is what I have in the first part for data

```
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      text: "test1",
      completed: false,
    }],
    text: '',
    show: 'all',
  },
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out the library axios for this task. Check out this example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html